# springframework.jdbc changes value after JdbcTemplate executes call stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, t-sql, spring-jdbc

I been using springframework.jdbc library to try retrieve data from my database in my webproject. For some reason this row in the trace:

```
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 15, parameter value [0.005], value class [java.math.BigDecimal], SQL type 2
```

Seems to convert the value that are sent to the class: 0.005 to 5 when I catch the request it in my sql server profiler. Just as the trace says the value that are sent to the class is of the type java.math.BigDecimal and I then use SQL type 2 in other word java.sql.Types.NUMERIC like in the bellow example:

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("Deviation", Types.NUMERIC));
```

What I suspect happens is something in the javalayer or hibernate sends only the BigInteger part of the BigDecimal value. How do I solve this, go around the problem? 
Any suggestion greatly appriachiated. I also inputed complete trace of what happens in the java at the lovest level that log4j can trace and what the SQL server profiler catches bellow.

Trace in java:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Calling stored procedure [{call sp_MyProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type -7
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 4, parameter value [329689], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 5, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 6, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 7, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 8, parameter value [2013-09-18], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 91
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 9, parameter value [2013-09-19], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 91
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 10, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 91
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 11, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 91
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 12, parameter value [false], value class [java.lang.Boolean], SQL type -7
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 13, parameter value [false], value class [java.lang.Boolean], SQL type -7
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 14, parameter value [false], value class [java.lang.Boolean], SQL type -7
<--Value that becomes converted bellow-->
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 15, parameter value [0.005], value class [java.math.BigDecimal], SQL type 2
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 16, parameter value [null], value class [null], SQL type 4
TRACE: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 17, parameter value [true], value class [java.lang.Boolean], SQL type -7
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - CallableStatement.execute() returned 'true'
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state 'S0001', error code '0', message [20130919: 2]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Trace in SQL server profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=8
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 bit,@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 date,@P8 date,@P9 date,@P10 date,@P11 bit,@P12 bit,@P13 bit,@P14 decimal(38,3),@P15 int,@P16 bit',N'EXEC sp_MyProcedure @P0, @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8, @P9, @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13, @P14, @P15, @P16                                                                                                                                 ',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,N'2013-09-18',N'2013-09-19',NULL,NULL,0,0,0,5,NULL,1
select @p1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have a value of `0.005` that sql-server converts to `5` internally? What are the data types involved?

Comment: Show us how you know it's `5` in the database.

Comment: I updated the case with more information on how the request are sent to the sql server. Jim To clarify how I know are because I have set a the trace to ALL on org.springframework.jdbc. The trace bellow:
<--Value that becomes converted bellow-->
Are changed to 5 when I use SQL Server Profiler to look at the same request.

Comment: I also complemented with an SQL server profiler trace.

Comment: Any suggestions or thoughts in the question?

Comment: @P14 decimal(38,3) looks good to me. What makes you dislike the trace? Can you take a peek in the database row?

Comment: With database row are you meaning the corresponding column in the procedure. That column is definied like this: @P14 NUMERIC(16,9) = NULL
I just see it as really wierd taht the actual value is 5 when it seems to be 0.005 in the javastacktrace just before being sent to the database. 
Could it be that I have to say to the javalayer that the numeric value should be on the format 16,9 or convert it to this format in some way?